Is there a way to ARP-query whether an IP address exists or not?
Is there a function that will send an ARP request and listen for ARP responses, so you can detect if a given IP address is taken on a local network?
I know it will happen as a side-effect of trying to send an ICMP ping or IP packet, but I'm looking for the direct solution, to avoid the higher level failure cases. I would like to avoid fiddling with ARP packets manually, since raw sockets require root access.
I know there is no way to know for sure if an IP is not taken, but that's fine: I just want to warn the user – "IP address already taken" – if the user is about to set themselves up for an IP address conflict that can be detected.

First attempt based on getaddrinfo:
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    for(size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        hints.ai_canonname = argv[1];
        int arpResolution = getaddrinfo(nullptr, nullptr, &hints, nullptr);
        if(arpResolution == EAI_AGAIN)
        {
            std::cout << "IP address " << argv[i] << " is available.\n";
        }
        else if(arpResolution == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "IP address " << argv[i] << " is taken.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << argv[i] << ": " << gai_strerror(arpResolution) << '\n';
        }
    }
}

It's quite possible I'm holding it wrong, but this fails miserably, even on localhost:

127.0.0.1: Name or service not known


Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language. It will help to get the right people looking at your question.
